# Is it possible to change the pop3 and ldap settings of Outlook with C#?

Tags: c#, outlook, pop3

Is it possible to change the password and other settings of a local Outlook client's pop3 with c#?  Any help is appreciated.  I did not have much luck searching.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) utilities.
At least, it has some API to query/modify Outlook acounts with the [RDOAccounts object model.](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/RDOAccounts.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I've done some work with AD in C# before, but I've never had to change AD settings.  I've had to change some user information but never any actual settings; however, I believe it is fully possible.

This website will show you how to do almost everything with the AD in c#.  I hope it helps.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx

**EDIT**

One important thing to remember, though, when modifying AD through C# is that security is still in place.  You will need to connect to the AD using a valid username/password that has rights to modify things.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't think I need to change the AD, however, just the local client.  It's hard to explain but they will already have their password.  I just need a way to enter it on the client in one place instead of tools, options, etc.

Comment: The I'm afraid that I am of no help :(.  But I'll leave this link up.  It's a great resource :).

Comment: How can I add a bounty?  I don't see a link.